# Why does .setAttribute not work with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(function () {
    $('textarea').setAttribute('style', 'height:' + ($('textarea').scrollHeight) + 'px;');
});
```

```html
<textarea>
    This is very, very long preloading text, I mean vvveeerrryyy, vvveeerrryyy long one!
</textarea>
```

What am I doing wrong, please? I double checked it, but can't find anything wrong

Comment: have you add the [jquery file](https://code.jquery.com/) in your html?

Comment: Yes, I did add the jQuery file, of course. https://jsfiddle.net/txt16afh/

Comment: [Open the browser's console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers), read the error message. If you want to set a style attribute, use [.css()](https://api.jquery.com/css/).

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a function `setAttribute()`

Comment: Next time, you should open the browser console. You would have seen right away what was wrong if you had. It is a tool that you will want to use whenever you are doing front-end web development, so better to learn it sooner.

Comment: Thank you. I'm googling right now about browser consoles.

Answer (score 3):

1. Its a [**`attr()`**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) .
2. change the `$('textarea').scrollHeight` into `$('textarea')[0].scrollHeight`.because it return undefined
3. `setAttribute()` is not defined function in jquery. And also Don't forget to add jquery library in your html.

```js
$(function () {
$('textarea').attr('style', 'height:' + ($('textarea')[0].scrollHeight) + 'px;');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>This is very, very long preloading text, I mean vvveeerrryyy, vvveeerrryyy long one!</textarea>
```

Comment: Oh, thank you. So it was just jQuey translation of JavaScript... I got it, thanks!

Comment: what does `$('textarea').scrollHeight` return ?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't have a function `setAttribute()`. Use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('textarea').attr('style', 'height:' + ($('textarea').scrollHeight) + 'px;');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>This is very, very long preloading text, I mean vvveeerrryyy, vvveeerrryyy long one!</textarea>
```

Comment: what does `$('textarea').scrollHeight` return ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following jquery

```
$('textarea').each(function () {
  this.setAttribute('style', 'height:' + (this.scrollHeight) + 'px;overflow-    y:hidden;');
})
```

Here is the working jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/1vpxmg4m/

Answer (score 0):

You can set height using jQuery `height()`

```
$('textarea').height(function(){
   return this.scrollHeight;
});
```